# Losing Observations in Logistic Regression in Stata

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, sample-size, stata

I have a data frame in Stata with 316 observations and I am trying to run some regression models on the data: none of the variables I am including in my model have missing data for these 316 observations, however, the observations used in the model drop to 278 - 286 depending on the model.

The general model is represented by this line of stata code

```
logit gov_winner gov_appellant i.new_other_litigant i.year i.circuit i.new_pty
```

What is causing the drop in observations and what can I do to fix it?

Thank you.

EDIT: Here are some example 'notes' that Stata gives me regarding the model.

```
    note: 4.new_other_litigant != 0 predicts failure perfectly
      4.new_other_litigant dropped and 1 obs not used

note: 5.new_other_litigant != 0 predicts failure perfectly
      5.new_other_litigant dropped and 1 obs not used

note: 13.circuit != 0 predicts success perfectly
      13.circuit dropped and 2 obs not used

note: 14.circuit omitted because of collinearity
Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -213.94206  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -206.63194  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -206.60839  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -206.60839
```

Comment: Do you see any "Note" messages either right under your command or right below the coefficient table? I suspect the culprit here is that some of your observations have variable values that predict success or failure perfectly, but Stata will generally alert you to the fact. Take a look at the Model Identification section of the logit chapter in the pdf manual to see some examples. This often happens when you have lots of dummies and continuous variables with repeated values, which you may have here.

Comment: Thank you so much, Dimitriy. I updated my question with some of the 'notes' stata outputs. Thank you!

Comment: Are there methods you recommend to overcome this issue? Thanks again!

Comment: This depends on your analysis goals. My initial response is that you have too many parameters given 316 observations. I would reduce model complexity, either by dropping some variables or recoding the variables to be coarser if that makes sense in your setting. Alternatively, go get some more data or try the `firthlogit`.

Comment: I think I will remove observations with the values of variables that are causing errors -- those values are not heavily represented in my database anyway (i.e. they are outliers). The small database size is definitely a problem but the data was expensive to collect (and was collected before model tools) so a larger database is not feasible. Also, if you post your comment as an 'answer' I will accept it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the culprit here is that some of your observations have variable values that predict success or failure perfectly, but Stata will generally alert you to the fact. Take a peek at the "note" output that Stata produces.

To understand this better, read the Model Identification section of the logit chapter in the pdf manual. This often happens when you have lots of dummies and continuous variables with repeated values, which you may have here.

You likely have too many parameters given 316 observations. I would reduce model complexity, either by dropping some variables or recoding the variables to be coarser if that makes sense in your setting. Alternatively, go get some more data or try the `firthlogit`, which handles complete separation better.